# connect multiple db using Sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

The code below is an attempt to connect more than one database using PHP PDO and SQLite. No matter what I tried, it does not accept the `select test1.table1`. If I remove the database name the `select` works; so how do I reference more than one database in the `select`?

```
<?php

  // connect to SQLite3 database 
  $query = "test1.sqlite3";
  $db = new PDO("sqlite:$query"); 

  // connect to second db
  $query = "attach test2.sqlite3";
  $db->query($query); 

  $query  = "Select * FROM test1.table1 ";
  $result = $db->query($query);
  $rows   = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<pre>".print_r($row)."</pre>";
  }  

?>
```

Comment: Please note that the [ATTACH statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) requires an AS clause; your second connection did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first database you connect to (`test1.sqlite3` in your case) is always called `main`, regardless of the actual filename. Try `SELECT * FROM main.table1`.